# Is there a name for the a position where King is on the first/last row and an enemy pawn is directly in front?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to figure out if there is any name for this particular position so that it might be easier for me to research it more - not so much the rook as much as having king behind the pawn. I play queenside castle a fair bit and find that if given the opportunity to get into this position it usually is beneficial.

```
[fen "1k1r4/pPp5/8/8/8/8/8/7K b - - 0 1"]
```

Here it is in one of my games from yesterday. (I'm sure there were better moves for probably both of us, this is just to better explain since the above kinda looks like endgame)

```
[FEN "1k1r3r/pPbn4/4p3/8/3Pp1B1/2q3pP/2P1Q1P1/R3K2R w KQ - 0 1"]
1.d4 e6 2.e3 d5 3.Nc3 Bd6 4.Nf3 Bd7 5.h3 Qe7 6.a3 Nf6 7.b4 Nc6 8.Be2 O-O-O 9.Bb2 h5 10.b5 Nb8 11.a4 Ne4 12.Nxe4 dxe4 13.Ne5 g5 14.Nxd7 Nxd7 15.a5 f5 16.b6 Kb8 17.bxc7+ Bxc7 18.a6 f4 19.Bc3 fxe3 20.fxe3 g4 21.axb7 g3 22.Bxh5 Qg5 23.Bg4 Qxe3+ 24.Qe2 Qxc3+ 0-1
```

Comment: I don't think there is a name for this.  If you have `Chessbase` or a similar database program you can perform a positional search for specific configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no explicit name for this position, but it is known that the pawn can act as a line of defense for the king. Its presence can obstruct the other side from creating a path towards the king as the pawn cannot be easily targeted.